# Using edit-config in Cordova to change InfoPlist.strings

Tags: ios, cordova

I am trying to use the following code to change the localization from English to French in Cordova, however it's not working. I am using PhoneGap Build, so editing the actual files this way is the only way.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<edit-config file="locales/fr.lproj/InfoPlist.strings" mode="overwrite" platform="ios" target="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription">

        <string>Always Usage French Reason</string>

</edit-config>

<edit-config file="locales/fr.lproj/InfoPlist.strings" mode="overwrite" platform="ios" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">

        <string>When In Usage French Reason</string>

</edit-config>
```